# Isn't pandas.Index.union() supposed to return the union of two Index objects?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

idx1 = pd.Index(list('abc'))
idx2 = pd.Index(list('aabbccdd'))

idx1.union(idx2)
```

Based on my understanding, the code above should return:

```bash
Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

But in reality, it returns:

```bash
Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

I've been searching online for a long time but still haven't found a reliable answer to this question. Did I misunderstand? How does it actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got confused because Python set's [`union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) gives a different result :

```
print(set(idx1).union(idx2)) # {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), if you want the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.unique.html) union, you can use :

```
print(idx1.union(idx2).unique()) # Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

As I understand it, pandas respects duplicates on purpose with its *behind-the-scenes* performed [`union`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L3217-L3337). At some point, this one uses [`union_with_duplicates`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/algorithms.py#L1691) :

```
       elif not other.is_unique:
            # other has duplicates
            result_dups = algos.union_with_duplicates(self, other)
            return _maybe_try_sort(result_dups, sort)
```

And here is what we can read from the docstring of the latter :

```
    """
    Extracts the union from lvals and rvals with respect to duplicates 
    and nans in both arrays.
    ...
    """
```